# TypeError: object of type 'ImageDataGenerator' has no len()

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

Instead of showing the accuracy, my cell keeps on getting the error "TypeError: object of type 'ImageDataGenerator' has no len()"

Here is my cell code:

````
# evaluate model
_, acc = classifier.evaluate_generator(test_datagen, steps=len(test_datagen), verbose=0)
print('> %.3f' % (acc * 100.0))```
````

Comment: you don't need to pass steps at all with ImageDataGenerator

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro when i removed the steps it says ```ValueError: `steps=None` is only valid for a generator based on the `keras.utils.Sequence` class. Please specify `steps` or use the `keras.utils.Sequence` class.``` Please help.

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest versions of Keras and that you are not mixing tf.keras and keras in impors, ImageDataGenerator is a Sequence

Answer (score 0):

- `len()` function in python takes list or string as argument, whereas `test_datagen` object is generator.
- To exactly know the length of the generator object try this `len(list(test_datagen))`

Comment: it says ```TypeError: 'ImageDataGenerator' object is not iterable```

Comment: Keras ImageDataGenerator is also a type of python generator object which generates batches of tensor image data.